# Load Regulation at -30C Temperatue

Tags: voltage, temperature, regulations

I was doing temperature testing of my product. Which had 230V input supply voltage Inside the product one SMPS module which convert 230Vac to 20Vdc. Again this 20Vdc converted to 5Vdc using DC to DC converter. I tested load regulation first at room temperature. I got following result

1) 5V  100mA =  5.010V,
2) 5V  300mA=   5.005V,
3) 5V  500mA=   4.998V,
4) 5V  750mA=   4.995V,
5) 5V  900mA=   4.990V

And when I test at -30C temperature

1) 5V  100mA =  5.004V,
2) 5V  300mA=   5.009V,
3) 5V  500mA=   5.012V,
4) 5V  750mA=   5.016V,
5) 5V  900mA=   5.019V

So at -30C temperature i observer voltage increase opposite what i observe at room temperature. Is this acceptable/Normal or this is so called temperature effect.

Comment: What does your requirement specification say?

Answer (score 3):

Look closely at the values

The first item varies from 5.010V to 5.004V. This is a variation of **-0.12%**

The second item varies from 5.005V to 5.009V. This is a variation of **-0.1%**

The third item varies from 4.995V to 5.016V. This is a variation of **0.4%**

The last item varies from 4.99V to 5.019%. This is a variation of **0.6%**

The [temperature coefficient of the resistors](http://www.vishay.com/resistors/change-resistance-due-to-rtc-calculator/) used for the feedback (to derive the external feedback voltage) added to the variation of the [internal reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply) (used to set the feedback *reference* voltage) alone can give this level of change across temperature.

As most power rails (there are, of course, exceptions) are 5%, then anything between 4.75V to 5.25V is usually acceptable.

As noted in a comment, whether this is acceptable depends on your requirements.

Comment: @Transformer -- Maybe the higher current output heats the components, negating a bit the effect of cold temp if compared to lighter loads?

Comment: But one thing here is with increase on Load current voltage decrease at room temperature and increase at -30C . Never Seen this before. In all other testing always seen voltage drop (little) with load current increase regardless with temperature

Answer (score 3):

Another way to say this is that the slope of the output impedance is slightly negative. When the supply output impedance becomes negative enough, it will oscillate.

I have seen this happen at cold temperatures. I had a precision power supply circuit that went into oscillation at about -10C. In my case, the root cause was that at cold temperatures, the gain of a transistor went down, and this decreased the phase margin of the voltage feedback. I fixed it by adding a compensation network to the feedback, which rolled off the gain at a lower frequency. This improved the phase margin at all temperatures, and solved the problem.

Comment: Excellent point on the temperature dependent slope.